# The initial s- which expresses a negative idea

Tags: etymology

I've noticed that a lot of nouns and verbs which begin with s- + consonant denote a negative and/or opposite idea. This doesn't seem to be a feature of other Latin-derived languages. How did this come about in Italian? Is there a list of such words that I could study?

Comment: Maybe it is a shortening of the Latin prefix `dis-`?

Comment: More like from Latin *ex-*.

Comment: See [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/s/) (a bit hard too find due to the not-too-friendly interface of Treccani).

Answer (score 4):

From the dictionary Sapere (De Agostini) : s- derives from the prep Latin. ex.

1. The prefix that confers meaning opposite verbs, nouns, adjectives
   (for example: fiorire-sfiorire; fiducia-sfiducia;
   contento-scontento).
2. In the derived adjectives from nouns and in some verbs derived
   also from nouns, the prefix acquires value privative
   pejorative (for example: natura-snaturato; ragione-sragionare).
3. In some verbs derived from nouns or by other verbs indicates
   away, exit, separation and the like, or suggests
   the idea of excess (for example: buca-sbucare; parlare-sparlare).
4. In other verbs derived from nouns or adjectives, buy
   privative value or detrattivo (for example: cardine-scardinare;
   vecchio-svecchiare).
5. Sometimes has intensive value (for example: gridare-sgridare).
6. In other cases it has function only derivative (for example:
   doppio-sdoppiare).
7. Sometimes represents the reduction of the prefix dis- (for example:
   dischiodare-schiodare).

Comment: Please, note that  here we have the policy of answering in English to a question posted in English and in Italian to a question posted in Italian. So could you please provide a translation to English to ensure that the OP can understand your answer?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I agree with you.